# Is it possible to write logical expression as parameter of JPQL coalesce function?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql

In JPQL it is possible to write:

```
select c from Car c where coalesce(c.wheels, 4) = 4
```

or, if you prefer working with bolts,

```
select c from Car c where coalesce(c.wheels * c.bolts, 20) = 20
```

However, if I try something like

```
select c from Car c where coalesce(c.wheels = 20, true)
```

it will fail. Hibernate log shows either empty coalesce() or "unexpected AST node" error.

Of course, this is a synthetic example; my code uses complicated expression with subselect that cannot be written in some other way easily. CASE also does not work. I wonder is there a way to write logical expressions in coalesce?

Update:

Last example does not work because comparision must be present (= true)

This works (boolean field):

```
select c from Car c where coalesce(c.tested, false) = true
```

This does not work (boolean expression):

```
select c from Car c where coalesce(c.wheels = 20, true) = true
```

Comment: Out of curiosity - did you check your last query but adding `= true` at the end? I could understand if that was required

Comment: Yes, it is possible, and is part of the JPQL BNF. Hence the problem is your JPA providers implementation of that function if it won't generate. The code looks correct IMHO

Comment: @Deltharis good point.

Comment: @NeilStockton I am not sure that it is part of JPQL BNF. It states that parameters of COALESCE are scalar expressions, not comparison expressions. It seems that this is not required by standard.